# Running jquery gallery makes links unclickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to build responsive webpage based on Zurb Foundation framework. Everything worked fine until I tried to add nanoGallery which uses jQuery too. When I add gallery scripts, top menu generated by Foundation script becomes unclickable, :hover works fine but if you click on it, nothing happens. Fell free to visit the exact page at http://emfoto.filipsvoboda.net/presentation.html.

This is how I'm trying to call each script:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).foundation();
</script>

<script src="third.party/transit/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
<script src="third.party/hammer.js/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="third.party/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.nanogallery.js"></script> 
<script>
    jQuery("#nanoGallery").nanoGallery({
    kind:'flickr',
    (..)
    thumbnailHoverEffect:[{'name':'borderLighter'}],
    thumbnailLabel:{display:false},
    });
</script>
```

I've already tried changing order of those scripts, but that does not seem to help.

**EDIT:** It does seem to work properly in IE10, however in Chrome-based browsers it still does not work.

**EDIT2:** After continual fiddling with the code it seems obvious that the presence of the gallery itself on that page causes the bug. Order of scripts doesn't seem to make any difference, as long as the gallery is not displayed, Foundation works correctly and links does work.

**EDIT3:** Updated the code, stripped it down and changed the order of scripts. I've added simple "a" link to the sample page and it doesn't work either.

**EDIT4:** I've searched for `event.preventDefault()` and it is present in one of the *.js files for the gallery. I've contacted the author and if we get to any solution I will post it here.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: for me everything is working perfectly.. with 'top menu' you mean domu,nanoGallery,galleria,kontakt ?

Comment: Options are clickable using Opera Mini (Android) but are not shown in grouped menu button (they appear expanded)

Comment: @Jenson Yes, those are that I meant. I tried other browsers, in IE10 it works, but in Chrome, Chrome for Android and Opera clicking still does nothing.

Comment: @chok68 Opera Mini doesn't load any of these scripts for me, the gallery is not displaying at all. That's I think is why it is clickable and appear expanded.

Comment: Some script you include on the page must be calling `event.preventDefault()` on click-events to links. Try searching that in the JavaScript-files.

Comment: YES! That's it! Thank you... Is there a way to mark your comment as a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in nanoGALLERY v4.2.1:

https://github.com/Kris-B/nanoGALLERY/releases/tag/4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I compared chrome and firefox requests and responses using Developer Extensions (chrome) and Firebug (firefox) for the info shown in Net panel. I'm not sure if the file that chrome doesn't find can be the cause of the problem but wanted to point out that difference.

**chrome**

- http://emfoto.filipsvoboda.net/third.party/hammer.js/hammer.min.map (Not found)
- http://emfoto.filipsvoboda.net/third.party/hammer.js/hammer.min.js

**firefox**     http://emfoto.filipsvoboda.net/third.party/hammer.js/hammer.min.js

Comment: I added the missing file, but that doesn't resolved the issue. After continual fiddling with the code it seems obvious that the presence of the gallery itself on that page causes the bug. Order of scripts doesn't seem to make any difference, as long as the gallery is not displayed, Foundation works correctly and links does work.

Answer (score 0):

Atleast for time being, you can have a workaround for this by having a click handler which will read the url and take the page to that url.

```
$(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        window.location.href = url;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm. I will use it for now. I've searched for `event.preventDefault()` and it is present in one of the *.js files for the gallery. I've contacted the author and if we get to any solution I will post it here.

Comment: I tried setting up debug point in each of the event.preventDefault() but somehow i was not able to find which one is creating the issue. Anyways good to know I was of some help. You can use this as an answer as long as you don't get the reply from the author cos there are 3 third party js you are referring to. Once you get the answer please add it in the question for reference.